# ArrayAccess vs. ArrayIndex in Expression Tree

Tags: c#, .net, linq, expression-trees

What is the difference between these 2? From the API documentation it seems like they were meant to do the exact same thing.

[ArrayAccess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383687.aspx)

vs.

[ArrayIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345296.aspx)

In which case they seem redundant, so I must be missing something here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Edit: My initial answer was so badly wrong that I'm trying again.*

`Expression.ArrayAccess` returns an `IndexExpression` which can be used to get or set the value of an element in an array.

`Expression.ArrayIndex` returns either a `BinaryExpression` or a `MethodCallExpression` depending on the rank (number of dimensions) of the provided array expression.  The returned expression can then be used to read a value from the array.

So `ArrayAccess` gives you an expression that provides both read and write access to the array data, while `ArrayIndex` gives you read access only.

Comment: It actually has overload, that takes multiple parameters.

Comment: I think the reason both exist is the way expression trees changed between .Net 3.5 and .Net 4. In 3.5, expression trees didn't support assignment, so there was only `ArrayIndex`. With 4, there was a need for something that would allow setting the value in an array, so `ArrayAccess` was added.