# How return vectors' scalar product using Expression trees

Tags: c#, .net-core, expression-trees, dynamicmethod

I try to return vectors' scalar product using expression trees, but I can not loop into arrays, can u help me? The task description and code please see below:

```
public class CodeGeneration
{
    public static Func<T[], T[], T> GetVectorMultiplyFunction<T>() where T : struct
    {
        // TODO : Implement GetVectorMultiplyFunction<T>.
            
        // Input
        ParameterExpression arr1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T[]), "first");
        ParameterExpression arr2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T[]), "second");
        ParameterExpression result = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "result");
            
        // Creating a label to jump to from a loop. 
        LabelTarget label = Expression.Label(typeof(int));
            
        // Creating a method body
        BlockExpression block = Expression.Block(
                            // Adding a local variable.  
                            new[] { result },
                            // Assigning a constant to a local variable: result = 1  
                            Expression.Assign(result, Expression.Constant(0)),
                                // Adding a loop.  
                                Expression.Loop(
                                   // Adding a conditional block into the loop.  
                                   Expression.IfThenElse(
    
    // ..........................               
    // I can not write the iteration for input arrays like the method below:
    // ..........................
            
                                       Expression.Break(label, result)
                                   ),
                               // Label to jump to.  
                               label
                            )
                        );
} 


// solution simple    
public static int MultiplyVectors(int[] first, int[] second)
{
    int result = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < first.Length; i++) 
    {
        result += first[i] * second[i];
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Does this have to use expressions?

Comment: I would be careful with using the word 'vector', since it has a more specific meaning than 'array'. If you want a 'vector' I would recommend creating an actual vector-type.  See for example [Math.Net vector](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double/Vector.htm) for inspiration.

Comment: Yes, this have to use expression trees!

Comment: Is your question how to get this as an expression? `Expression<Func<int[], int[], int>> lambda = (arr1, arr2) => arr1.Zip(arr2).Sum(x => x.First * x.Second);`

Answer (score 2):

If all you need is an expression, then for "single" lambda statements you can just declare an expression:

```cs
Expression<Func<double[], double[], double>> lambda = (arr1, arr2) => arr1.Zip(arr2).Sum(x => x.First * x.Second);
```

But it sounds like this is homework problem, so at least you can use the above for testing.

---

You need to declare a loop variable, and increment it in the loop. ~ [How to create a loop expression tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55183456/how-to-create-a-loop-expression-tree)

You will also need [`Expression.ArrayAccess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.arrayaccess?view=net-6.0) to retrieve value of an array.

You also need to get the array length. Probably you can simply use `Expression.ArrayLength`, but because you are using generics, it might be safer to retrieve the `Length` property ~ [Expression getting length of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50455090/expression-getting-length-of-an-array)

Putting this all together:

```cs
public static Func<T[], T[], T> BuildExpression<T>()
{
    ParameterExpression result = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "result");
    ParameterExpression i = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "i");
    ParameterExpression firstLength = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "firstLength");

    ParameterExpression firstArrayExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T[]), "FirstArray");
    ParameterExpression secondArrayExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T[]), "SecondArray");

    // How to get length of an array
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50455090/expression-getting-length-of-an-array
    MethodInfo arrayLengthGetter = typeof(Array).GetProperty("Length").GetGetMethod();

    // Label target needs to be same as return type
    LabelTarget label = Expression.Label(typeof(T));

    /////

    // Following is expression "method", double slash comments (//) are code the expression implements,
    // double double slash comments (////) are higher level comments.

    var methodBody = Expression.Block(
        //// local variables
        new[] { result, i, firstLength },

        // result = default(T);
        Expression.Assign(result, Expression.Constant(default(T))),

        // firstLength = FirstArray.Length;
        Expression.Assign(firstLength, Expression.Call(firstArrayExpr, arrayLengthGetter)),

        // while (true) {
        Expression.Loop(
            Expression.Block(
                Expression.IfThenElse(
                    // if (i < firstLength) {
                    Expression.LessThan(i, firstLength),
                    //    result += FirstArray[i] * SecondArray[i];
                    Expression.AddAssign(result, Expression.Multiply(

                        //// how to access array by index
                        //// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.arrayaccess?view=net-6.0
                        //// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14973813/arrayaccess-vs-arrayindex-in-expression-tree
                        Expression.ArrayAccess(firstArrayExpr, i),
                        Expression.ArrayAccess(secondArrayExpr, i)
                        )),
                    // } else { 
                    //     goto label;
                    // }
                    Expression.Break(label, result)
                    ),
                // i += 1;
                Expression.AddAssign(i, Expression.Constant(1))
            ),
        // } //// end while
        //// `while` break target:
            label
    ));

    var func = Expression.Lambda<Func<T[], T[], T>>(methodBody, firstArrayExpr, secondArrayExpr);

    return func.Compile();
}
```

With the `MultuplyVectors` declared above, you can test with (note I changed the types to `double` to demo generic `T`):

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var list1 = new List<double>() { 2, 4, 7, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 };
    var list2 = new List<double>() { 3, 6, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 };

    Expression<Func<double[], double[], double>> lambda = (arr1, arr2) => arr1.Zip(arr2).Sum(x => x.First * x.Second);
    var f = lambda.Compile();

    var expr = BuildExpression<double>();

    var fsum = f(list1.ToArray(), list2.ToArray());
    var calcsum = MultuplyVectors(list1.ToArray(), list2.ToArray());
    var exprsum = expr.Invoke(list1.ToArray(), list2.ToArray());

    Console.WriteLine($"fsum: {fsum}");
    Console.WriteLine($"calcsum: {calcsum}");
    Console.WriteLine($"exprsum: {exprsum}");
}
```

console output:

```
fsum: 823
calcsum: 823
exprsum: 823
```

Note: in visual studio debugger, there is a debug (visual studio runtime) only property on `Expression` called DebugView which will explain how the expression is defined. For example

```cs
.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`3[System.Double[],System.Double[],System.Double]>(
    System.Double[] $FirstArray,
    System.Double[] $SecondArray) {
    .Block(
        System.Double $result,
        System.Int32 $i,
        System.Int32 $firstLength) {
        $result = 0D;
        $firstLength = .Call $FirstArray.get_Length();
        .Loop  {
            .Block() {
                .If ($i < $firstLength) {
                    $result += $FirstArray[$i] * $SecondArray[$i]
                } .Else {
                    .Break #Label1 { $result }
                };
                $i += 1
            }
        }
        .LabelTarget #Label1:
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what to say, u helped me a lot, thanks a lot mate, u are super!

Comment: sorry but I ma fresher at stackoverflow, that says: Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded. :( Don't worry I will do it in a short time :)

Comment: @Anagureli you need to press on the checkmark to the left of the answer.